# How come "json_encode( $custom_query['query_vars'" is NULL?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

When parsing variables from a PHP function using wp_localize_script into a jQuery script result in a NULL variable, which I don't understand why.

I hope someone else does notice the problem.

Following function within function.php is parsing variables into jQuery script:

```
function wordpress_my_load_more_scripts() 
    {
        global $custom_query; 

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/myloadmore.js', array('jquery') );

        wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'wordpress_loadmore_params', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'posts' => json_encode( $custom_query['query_vars'] ),
            'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
            'max_page' => json_encode($custom_query['max_num_pages'])
        ));

        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );

    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wordpress_my_load_more_scripts' );
```

Following jQuery script writes data variable into console:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.wordpress_loadmore').click(function()
    { 
        var button = $(this),
            data = {
            'action' : 'loadmore',
            'query': wordpress_loadmore_params.posts,
            'page' : wordpress_loadmore_params.current_page

        };

        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            url : wordpress_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) 
            {
                console.log("Loading");

                button.text('Loading...');
            },
            success : function( data )
            {
                console.log("Success");

                if(data) 
                { 
                    console.log("We got data!");
                    console.log(wordpress_loadmore_params.current_page);
                    console.log(wordpress_loadmore_params.max_page);

                    button.text( 'More posts' ).prev().before(data);
                    wordpress_loadmore_params.current_page++;

                    if ( wordpress_loadmore_params.current_page == wordpress_loadmore_params.max_page ) 
                    {
                        console.log("Last page! Remove button");

                        button.remove();
                    }

                } else {

                    console.log("No data! Remove button");

                    button.remove();                }
            },
            error: function() 
            {
                console.log("Error");            
            }
        });
    });
});
```

console.log(data); outputs following message:

```
(index):27 Debug Objects: 
jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:23 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1
myloadmore.js:12 {action: "loadmore", query: "null", page: "1"}
myloadmore.js:20 Loading
myloadmore.js:26 Success
myloadmore.js:30 We got data!
myloadmore.js:31 1
myloadmore.js:32 null
```

Why is the query NULL?

This is the custom query:

```
<div class="woocommerce columns-3">
                    <ul class="products columns-3">

                        <?php 

                        $query_params = array(
                                'post_type' => 'post',
                                'posts_per_page' => 3 // Value "-1" displays all products in feed
                        );

                        $custom_query = new WP_Query( $query_params);        

                        if( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :

                            while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

                                <li class="product post-item">
                                    <span class="post-image">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                            <?php 
                                                if ( has_post_thumbnail()) 
                                                {
                                                    the_post_thumbnail();
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                    <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                    <span class="post-category"><?php the_category(', ');?></span>
                                </li>

                            <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </ul>

                    <nav>
                        <?php

                        // global $custom_query; // you can remove this line if everything works for you

                        // don't display the button if there are not enough posts
                        if (  $custom_query->max_num_pages > 1 )
                            echo '
                                <div class="wordpress_wrapper">
                                    <div class="wordpress_loadmore">More posts</div>
                                </div>'; // you can use <a> as well
                        ?>
                    </nav>

                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                </div>
```

Link to current solution - https://www.uvjagtpro.dk/arkiv/

Comment: this file where you say the enqueue, is set in enqueue.php ?

Comment: You need to do a `var_dump($custom_query['query_vars'])` and show us what it contains. Are they other variables set?

Comment: Make sure that you have error reporting turned on and check your servers error log.

Comment: Only the first XHR of this page, response "We have post(s)!A post!", 
/* <![CDATA[ */
var wordpress_loadmore_params = {"ajaxurl":"https:\/\/www.uvjagtpro.dk\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","posts":"null","current_page":"1","max_page":"null"};
/* ]]> */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially solved my problem here.

I was not able to use the custom WP_query from the original loop. I had to define a new WP_query within the wordpress_my_load_more_scripts() function.

See below:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wordpress_my_load_more_scripts' );

function wordpress_my_load_more_scripts() 
{


    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    $query_args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 3, 
        'post_type'         => 'artikler',
        'paged'             => $paged
    );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $query_args);

    if (!isset( $wp_query ))
    {
        debug_to_console("Query is NULL!");

        return;
    }

    wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', plugins_url( 'myloadmore.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );

    $postArray = array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), 
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'results' => $wp_query->found_posts
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'wordpress_load_more_params', $postArray);

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );

}
```

Output to console is now this:

```
{action: "load_more", query: "{"posts_per_page":3,"post_type":"artikler","paged"…_page":"50","no_found_rows":false,"order":"DESC"}", max: "4", page: "1", results: "10"}
action:"load_more"
max:"4"
page:"1"
query:"{"posts_per_page":3,"post_type":"artikler","paged":1,"error":"","m":"","p":0,"post_parent":"","subpost":"","subpost_id":"","attachment":"","attachment_id":0,"name":"","static":"","pagename":"","page_id":0,"second":"","minute":"","hour":"","day":0,"monthnum":0,"year":0,"w":0,"category_name":"","tag":"","cat":"","tag_id":"","author":"","author_name":"","feed":"","tb":"","meta_key":"","meta_value":"","preview":"","s":"","sentence":"","title":"","fields":"","menu_order":"","embed":"","category__in":[],"category__not_in":[],"category__and":[],"post__in":[],"post__not_in":[],"post_name__in":[],"tag__in":[],"tag__not_in":[],"tag__and":[],"tag_slug__in":[],"tag_slug__and":[],"post_parent__in":[],"post_parent__not_in":[],"author__in":[],"author__not_in":[],"ignore_sticky_posts":false,"suppress_filters":false,"cache_results":true,"update_post_term_cache":true,"lazy_load_term_meta":true,"update_post_meta_cache":true,"nopaging":false,"comments_per_page":"50","no_found_rows":false,"order":"DESC"}"
results:"10"
__proto__:Object
```

Answer (score 1):

That `null` you are seeing is not of type `null` but of type `string` (I just checked your website). Which means that you actually do something like:  `json_encode("null")`.

It seems you are trying to load the `query_vars` and `max_num_pages` as an array:

```
'posts' => json_encode( $custom_query['query_vars'] ),
'max_page' => json_encode($custom_query['max_num_pages'])
```

But I guess those are object properties, like in the other file:

```
if (  $custom_query->max_num_pages > 1 )
```

So I guess if you rewrite them to this it should work:

```
'posts' => json_encode( $custom_query->query_vars ),
'max_page' => json_encode($custom_query->max_num_pages)
```

Probably the `$custom_query` object has some ArrayAccess interface I guess, that's why you can access that object as an array, and it doesn't throw a warning or error.

Comment: If it does implement the `ArrayAccess`-interface, then your example wouldn't make any difference. But who knows. It could also be that the OP doesn't have error reporting turned on, and then your solution could work.

Comment: I just looked it up, and WP_Query [uses magic calls](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2361ca884f562e996fffd1ee373f29f75d41aff3/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L3495) , which should return the value of a queried field. If none found it will return nothing (or null). If you do a `console.log(wordpress_loadmore_params)` on his website, you can see that the `null` is a string. Which means that json_encode was either given the null type or the string `null`. Considering both facts, I'm pretty sure it's because it's an object.